# Liquibase - insert new row based on data from existing column

Tags: sql, liquibase

If I have a DB table like:

Column 1 Column 2
Data1, Data2a
Data2, Data2b
Data3, Data2a

Is it possible to create a liquibase changeset script to get all the unique values from Column 2, and use that data to insert new rows?

Such that my final table could look like (Actual values of Column 1 inserted will be manually defined by myself)

Column 1 Column 2
Data1, Data2a
Data2, Data2b
Data3, Data2a
Data4, Data2a //Got this value from initial table
Data5, Data2b //Got this value from initial table

Comment: This will be quite easy using a SQL query in a  `<sql>` tag. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: This script would hopefully be used for multiple Databases - Oracle, postgresql, mysql and SQL server

Comment: It can be done with a statement that runs on Oracle, Postgres and SQL Server. But as MySQL doesn't support [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) you will need to use tags specific for each DBMS

Comment: Do you mean I need 4 separate SQL tags with statements? Where Oracle, Postgresql SQL server will be the same but MySQL statement would be slightly different?

Comment: You can set multiple databases for sql query using precondition/dbms/or: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html